# JavaScript push method changing values

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Node shell to test this: BTW, I am new to Javascript

```
x = [1,2]
y = [3,4]
k = []
for ( n in x.concat(y) ) { k.push(n); }
```

Now typing k prints the following:

```
[ '0', '1', '2', '3' ]
```

Comment: What's the expected output? Is it `[1,2,3,4]`? By the way `n` is the index, not the value. That's why you see the `0...n-1`.

Comment: `for..in` is not `foreach`; not exactly. maybe you understand the result if you try `x=[7,8], y=[6,5]`

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek – More specifically, it is a `key` than `index`.. Correct me If I am wrong..

Comment: @Rayon It would be indexes since it's an array.

Comment: [Note: for...in should not be used to iterate over an Array where the index order is important.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in)

Comment: n is the index in for loop

Comment: @misgevolution, for in loop provide index, whereas for of loop (in ES6) provide values. :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no need of for loop at all simply assign the **[`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)** method return value, which is the concatenated array.

```
var k = x.concat(y)
```

---

**FYI :** In [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop you are getting the key, in case it will be the array index. It's designed to use for object iteration. Use [simple for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) instead. Even **[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** or **[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** can be used, as per your requirement.

An example with  **[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** :

```
a.concat(b).forEach(function(e){
   k.push(e);
});
```

---

In case if you want to push an array of values to an existing array then use **[`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)** with **[`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply)** method.

```
[].push.apply(existingArray, arrayOfValuesToPush);
```

In your case it would be :

```
[].push.apply(k, a.concat(b));
// or
[].push.apply(k, a);
[].push.apply(k, b);
```

Comment: Clearly, this person knows how to use `concat`, since `concat` is in the code itself...  The `for...in` is what is in question here.

Comment: Well, what if I want to append to an existing list k?

Comment: @Misgevolution : at that case use `[].push.apply(k,a)` , where `k` is existing array and `a` is the array you want to concatenate

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to the element instead of index of the array

```
for ( n in _m=x.concat(y)) {
 k.push(_m[n]); 
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/1qs1gyrt/1/)

Comment: Better than declaring the object at a higher scope. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're using a `for...in` loop on a data structure that doesn't typically operate with key/value pairs.

So what's actually happening is in each iteration of your `for...in` loop, you're passing the index to n and pushing that index to a new array.

What you're probably wanting is actually the [`forEach` method native to arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Which changes your code to be something like this...

```
var x = [1,2];
var y = [3,4];
var k = [];
x.concat(y).forEach(function(element, index) {
 k.push(element);
}
```

There's also the [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method also native to arrays that will actually produce an entirely new array (instead of you having to define `k` and `push` to it.

```
var x = [1,2];
var y = [3,4];

var k = x.concat(y).map(function(element, index) {
 // the return value is the element that will be at the
 // new array's index. 
 return element; 
}
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about the existence of forEach.

Comment: I also added an example for map! Which will achieve the same thing, but a little more concisely :)

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing the index, not the actual elements.  Try something like this:

```
var x = [1,2];
var y = [3,4];
var k = [];

var z = x.concat(y);
for (var n in z) {
  k.push(z[n]);
}
```

Read more here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: **There is no guarantee that for...in will return the indexes in any particular order. **

Comment: @paradite What difference does that make?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking the C++ way and was hastily trying to implement some js component.

Comment: The point is `for in` does not guarantee order `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, it might return `[2, 1, 3, 4]` as a matter of specification, which is not expected.

Comment: @paradite Yes, and what does that have to do with anything?  Why would that not be expected?  You're misunderstanding the fact that `[1, 2, 3, 4]` is clearly an example array and not the actual data in question.  The issue here was that Misgenvolution didn't realize that in JS, the iterator variable is the index of the element for that current iteration, not that element itself.

Comment: The issue here is `for in` is not supposed to be used to iterate arrays, because it does not guarantee order. The author clearly wants to iterate array in the same way as `for in` in other languages like C++ or Java, which guarantees order. To iterate array, it is better to use simple for loop or `forEach`.

Comment: @paradite `for...in` can be used to iterate on arrays all you want.  Did you read the question?  Did you read my answer?  Comments like yours are distracting and confusing to people new to something, at least when put in the context of a Q&A like you've done.  If you wanted to leave a comment for the person asking the question, specifically calling out that your comment has nothing to do with the specific question, and that he should be aware of the caveats with `for...in`, go ahead.

Comment: @paradite For example, I often leave comments like this:  "This isn't your current problem, but you have an SQL injection vulnerability in your code.  Rather than [code here] it would be better to [code here].  You can read more about this issue here [link here]."  You might consider doing that instead, so as not to confuse everyone.

Comment: @paradite This question is simply using `for..in` because the question is using it. The OP never stated what the output is supposed to be or if the order of the array matters (*it's likely it does, but the OP needs to state so*). Anyways I've already noted in a comment in the question to not use `for..in` to iterate arrays if index order is important, it's a problem you should discus with the OP rather than an answerer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (in ES5):

```
var k = x.concat(y);
```

Try this (in ES6):

```
for (let n of x.concat(y)) {
  k.push(n);
}
```

Comment: Yep, i'm providing him short & simple answer without confusing into couple of things.